# Is there a way to retrieve body asynchronously with Tornado server from a POST/PUT?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, aiohttp

With aiohttp server, it is possible to `await`the request body asynchronously, that way it gives the hand back to the event loop:

```
async def post_handler(request):
    data = await request.json()
    return aiohttp.web.Response(status = 201, body = data, content_type='application/json')
```

However using Tornado I can't find a way to make it asynchronously. 
The only way to retrieve the body is this:

```
async def post(self):
    data = self.request.body
    self.write(data)
```

Therefore, if the client sends a big file, the tornado event loop will block until the whole body is retrieve, am I right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the event loop is not blocked. `post()` is not run until the body is already fully loaded. To process the body incrementally, see the `@stream_request_body` decorator.